# EditText Covers by the soft key board

Tags: xml

I am creating this app with two editText and a button in a Linearlayout Fragment.But when click to enter the second editText the soft keyboard covers the editText view.  I need to set the soft keyboard not to cover the second editText. I tried `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"` in my manifest also.
This is my XML code.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.shagee.unipoint.PointsFragment">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/black_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Add Points"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

                    <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/addPointsRadioGroup"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/addPointsRadioInvoiceNo"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Invoice Number" />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/addPointsRadioBillValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Bill Value" />
                    </RadioGroup>

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/PointsFragmentInvoiceNumET"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:hint="Invoice Number"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/PointsFragmentPhoneNumET"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:hint="Mobile Number"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/PointsFragmentAddPointsBtn"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/add_points_button"
                        android:padding="3dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Add Points" />
                </LinearLayout>


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- REDEEM POINTS SECTION RIGHT SIDE-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:background="@color/black_color"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Redeem Points"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="#FFFF"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/RedeemPointsInvoiceNumET"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:hint="Bill Amount"
                        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/RedeemPointsNoOfPointsET"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:hint="Number of Points"
                        android:inputType="number"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/RedeemPointsPhoneNumET"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:hint="Mobile Number"
                        android:inputType="phone"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/RedeemPointsBtn"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="75dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/redeem_points_button"
                        android:text="Redeem Points" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In a device, it looks like this.

[image: Before Clicking Second EditText]

[image: After Clicking EditText]

Comment: add your manifest file here

Comment: and this xml code you shared is it of your activity , if yes what is the name of this activity

Comment: MainActivity and this is the manifest files `<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
    />`

Comment: Hi Sahan , Check the below code , if you are using fragment it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make Sure , you are adding the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` into the respective correct Activity.

*if you are using* **EditTexts inside Fragment** then in your **onCreate method inside fragment add this below code**:-

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: yes i put it `<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
    />`

Comment: check the updated answer if you are using fragment it will 100% work for you

Comment: i am glad to help you

Comment: If you want to learn more. Please check this page. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams