# Screen keeps moving while typing when EditText is in focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-screen

My EditText is positioned below an ImageView. When I start typing on the EditText, the screen won't stay put and keeps scrolling up and down as shown in [this video](https://streamable.com/ig4lk). Another problem is the keyboard covers part of the EditText.

This is what my activity's XML looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/display_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/caption_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:theme="@style/LoginFieldLayout"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/MomentLabel">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_start_photo_story_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:hint="@string/caption_hint"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine"
            android:lines="8"
            android:maxLength="500"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:privateImeOptions="nm"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:theme="@style/StartAdventureEditText" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I've also added this line in the manifest file: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`.

Comment: are you using EditText in any Fragment

Comment: My app is using fragments but not in this particular activity.

Comment: if you are using EditText inside a Fragment for this screen , check my answer here hope it helps you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48414946/edittext-covers-by-the-soft-key-board/48414991#48414991

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "adjustNothing" as below in your androidManifestFile.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.myApp.ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustNothing" />
    <activity
```

Comment: Thanks. That did solve my issue. However, as you could see in the video, there's a live character count right below the EditText. Is there a way to slightly scroll up the screen when the EditText is in focus so that the live character count won't be covered by the soft keyboard?

Comment: This is because you have a manual swiftkey keyboard. However, below will help you by truncating the hieght of keyboard(disabling the suggestions).

<EditText
android:inputType="textFilter|textMultiLine/>